# Discard rows which is not MAX in that group

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have data like this:

```
   a       b        c
-------|--------|--------
  100  |   3    |   50
  100  |   4    |   60
  101  |   3    |   70
  102  |   3    |   70
  102  |   4    |   80
  102  |   5    |   90
```

`a` : key
`b` : sub_id
`c` : value

I want to NULL the `c` row for each element which has non-max `a` column.

My resulting table must look like:

```
   a       b        c
-------|--------|--------
  100  |   3    |  NULL
  100  |   4    |   60
  101  |   3    |   70
  102  |   3    |  NULL
  102  |   4    |  NULL
  102  |   5    |   90
```

How can I do this with an SQL Query?

**#UPDATE**

My relational table has about a billion rows. Please remind that while providing an answer. I cannot wait couple of hours or 1 day for executing.

Comment: You want to update the original table or return a processed resultset?

Comment: Yes what? Update or select?

Comment: Oh sorry, want to update.

Comment: @totten: What exactly *non-max `a` column* means? Max value of `B` or `C` within given value of `A`?

Comment: It must be like @Jithin Shaji answer.

Comment: @totten: do you have an index on `(a, c)`? If you have ties (multiple records sharing the max value of `C` within a single `A`), do you want them all stay as is, or leave a single value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated after the requirement was changed to "update the table":

```
with max_values as (
  select a,
         b,
         max(c) over (partition by a) as max_c
  from the_table
)
update the_table   
    set c = null
from max_values mv
   where mv.a = the_table.a
     and mv.b = the_table.b
     and mv.max_c <> the_table.c;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e739/1

Another possible solution, which might be faster (but you need to check the execution plan)

```
update the_table t1
  set c = null
where exists (select 1 
              from the_table t2
              where t2.a = t1.a
                and t2.b = t2.b 
                and t1.c < t2.c);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e739/2

But with "billion" rows there is no way this is going to be really fast.

Comment: Want to change the original table though.

Comment: @totten: see my update - but I don't think this can be done in an efficient manner.

Comment: Your query gives an error: 

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 4:          MAX(c) over (partition by a) as max_c`

Comment: @totten: you might also want to try my second solution. That _could_ be faster (but it's hard to tell)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (A INT,B INT,C INT)
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES
(100,3,50),
(100,4,60),
(101,3,70),
(102,3,70),
(102,4,80),
(102,5,90)


UPDATE      X
SET         C = NULL
FROM        @TAB X
LEFT JOIN   (
            SELECT  A,MAX(C) C 
            FROM    @TAB
            GROUP   BY A) LU ON X.A = LU.A AND X.C = LU.C
WHERE       LU.A IS NULL

SELECT * FROM @TAB
```

Result:

[image]

this approach will help you

Comment: That is not valid for Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why not?

Comment: Just try it. `DECLARE @TAB TABLE (A INT,B INT,C INT)` will give the first error. Also `left join` is not valid in an `update` statement. Did you ever work with Postgres at all?

Answer (score 1):

How about this formulation?

```
select a, b,
       (case when c = max(c) over (partition by a) then c end) as c
from table t;
```

I'm not sure if you can get this faster.  An index on `a, c` might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a, b,
        CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b DESC) WHEN 1 THEN с END c
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: @totten: too slow for what?

Comment: For a billion rows of table.

Comment: @totten: define "too"

Comment: ORDERing a table partition instead of selecting MAX, isn't it slower?

Comment: @totten: unless you have an index on `(a, b)`, you have to sort first to find `MAX` anyway.